# AWK: print only lines not matching the defined pattern

Tags: regex, awk

I'd like to make AWK only print lines that don't match the following pattern:
 `awk -F'-' 'NF>7'`
(lines in which - appears more than 7times)

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thank you very much

Comment: Stick a `!` in front of it or change the comparison from `>` to `<=`.

Comment: Changing the comparison works, I had not thought of that ! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Stick a `!` in front of it or change the comparison from `>` to `<=`.

Comment: Not that I think the logical negation the best way to write this, but I guess the advice should be "stick a `!` in front of it _and add parentheses around `NF>7`_", otherwise you just evaluate `!NF`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not tied to using Awk, GNU Grep can do it:
Code:

```
grep -Ev '<your regex>'
```

The -v option means show lines that don't match, -E means use extended regular expressions

Comment: That only works for regexes. `NF > 7` isn't exactly a regex (although you could write a regex with the same effect, it wouldn't be as compact).